# Is there a way to embed and style a Wikipedia article in a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

What I want to do is basically a div-Element containing the print-friendly version of Wikipedia articles. I used an iframe to embed articles and it works, though I cannot style the document. I guess this is because the iframe content is not on my domain and I do not have editing rights. Is there a way to apply css styling to the content after the iframe is loaded?

Comment: Download it with server-side script, modify paths to css and so on, insert the result into your page.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I lack the knowledge to do the server side download. Would you use PHP for that?

Comment: PHP, Perl, Python, .. whatever you can run on server-side. Even by wget + bash

Comment: what about this https://embed.ly/provider/wikipedia (3rd party service)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with AJAX by calling the wiki api with custom query string parameters.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/fm0vxg32/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Jimi_Hendrix&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
            var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
            $('#article').html($(blurb).find('p'));

        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#article {
  // custom styling
}
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` - You aren't making a POST or PUT request so there is no request body to describe the content type of. `async: false` blocks all JS while the HTTP request is make, 99.99% of the time, that is a terrible idea.

Comment: Wow, this is by far the easiest and best solution so far. Though it seems like the API gives me the introductiory text of the page only. Is it possible to change this behaviour in the settings?

Comment: As already mentioned by @Quentin, there's almost no use case that allows the usage of `async: false`. Use a spinner, fade the content in as soon as it's available or inform the user that something happend. Except for that a useful answer.

Comment: I noticed that when i change the `section=0` in the url I can load different passages of the article. IS there a method to load the whole article?

Comment: @YuliyanIlev: Just omit the `section` parameter

Comment: 2019 update: change url from "http" to "https" so Chrome will not block the request due to an insecure connection if you're using SSL encryption (as on jsfiddle).